# What is the differences between normal equation and gradient descent for polynomial regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm new to machine learning and willing to study and work with machine learning. It just that I still don't get to understand the benefits of using normal equation in some occasion in comparison with gradient descent. I use Andrew Ng's course on Coursera but the notation really makes me a hard time to understand.

I want to know more about the derivation of the cost function `J(ō)` for polynomial regression and the reason why he uses the transpose of vector `x(i)`

Comment: Consider asking theoretically motivated questions over at the [Datas Science Stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or the [Stats Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Generally, SO should be specifically for programming-focused questions!

Answer (score 0):

Normal Equation is beneficial in cases where we don't need to choose alpha. Also, it is an non-iterative algorithm, so you will be able to minimize the cost function within less time(only when number of features are less).

Since, normal equation works with matrices and its inverse, it is relatively a computationally expensive approach as compared to Gradient Descent approach in cases where number of features are large.

Refer to the below link for derivation of cost function for Polynomial regression :
[Cost function for Polynomial regression](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~shalab/regression/Chapter12-Regression-PolynomialRegression.pdf)